# Wrong relative path for all files including images and css

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

All files including css and images keep hitting my Home/Index Controller becuse it is taking wrong relative path

here are my routes:

```
    routes.MapRoute("MainRoute", "{lang}/{topic}/{sort}/{page}", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", page = 1 }, new { lang = @"\D{2}", page = @"\d+" });

    routes.MapRoute("MyLang", "{lang}/{page}", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", page = UrlParameter.Optional }, new { lang = @"\D{2}" });

    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapHttpRoute(name: "DefaultApi", routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}", defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });

    routes.MapRoute(name: "Default", url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}", defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

When I am at path `http://localhost:xxxx/en/all/recent` and try to go to `http://localhost:xxxx/en/all/recent/2` I get and error becuse all my files keep hitting

```
~/en/Content/Site.css
```

instead of 
`~/Content/Site.css`

so everything goes to my Home/index controller.

I really don't know where to look for problems since I didn't change routes from when I started writing this code and I just recently noticed this but it seems like routing problem, can someone take a look at my routes or point me where the error might be.

UPDATE:

If i try to go ignore css and images not found and procced when I click page back I get this: `http://localhost:xxxx/en/all/recent/en/all/recent/1`

Comment: How you generate links to content and to actions? Do you include language parameter also?

Comment: @Slim I solved It partialy, I was using raw paths in all links which were obviously wrong, things started working when I started using `@Url.Content("relative-paths")` for everything: files,scripts,images etc. and Link helpers for actions, but still I can't use hardcoded paths in external jQuery/Js files, Instead I have to pass path in var or use inline scripts, so it's more of a hack, but I guess it works.